# Fatal error: Call to a member function isNew() on a non-object symfony 1.4

Tags: object, symfony-1.4, php, fatal-error

I am getting this fatal error when running a condition to see if this is a new record, and if so, create a duplicate draft record in the database.

**actions.class.php**

```
$this->form = new AlertsForm($active_alert);
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
      $this->form->bind($request->getParameter('alerts'), $request->getFiles('alerts'));
      if ($this->form->isValid()) {
        try {
          /* check if record is the draft version, and if not create one */

          if (!$active_alert->isNew() && !$active_alert['is_preview'] && 
              ($request->getParameter('button_type') != 'publish' || 
              !$this->getUser()->hasPublishingPrivilege())) {

            $active_alert = $active_alert->createDraft();
            $values = $request->getParameter('alerts');
            $values['id'] = $active_alert['id'];
            $this->form = new AlertsForm($active_alert);
            $this->form->bind($values, $request->getFiles('alerts'));

            $this->getUser()->setFlash('draft', true);
          }
```

**Error:**

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isNew() on a non-object in apps/cms/modules/alerts/actions/actions.class.php on line 35
```

If I run a var_dump on `$active_alert`, it returns:

> bool(false)

Older working versions of this piece of code are identical, so I am not sure it is this exact code that is wrong, I just do not know where to look.

Comment: Hint: when doctrine doesn't find a record in the database it gives back false.

Comment: Can we see how do you create `$active_alert`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Fatal Error is because, as the error message suggests, there's no $active_alert, i.e. it is a non-object, and you're trying to call `isNew()` on a non-object.

What you can do is check for the existence of `$active_alert` before checking if it's (not) new:

`if ($active_alert && !$active_alert->isNew() && !$active_alert['is_preview'] && ...`